# How to destroy a usercontrol to free memory?

Tags: .net, wpf, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm working on a WPF application, I have a method let's call it **GetUIElement()**, my method returns a **CustomUserControl**, and I have a for loop in which I call **GetUIElement**, the problem is when I have 1000 iterations in the for loop my application consumes too much memory.

PS :

- Even when I change **GetUIElement()** signature to return a simple Button, I can see the memory growing
- In the constructor and the destructor of **CustomUserControl** I put some debug code to get an idea about the life cycle of my objects, and I saw that they are all destroyed at the same time after the loop, wich explain why my application consumes too much memory, they are all kept in memory until the end of the loop.
  I hope I was clear, dont hesitate to tell me if you want more explanation.
  and here is some portions of the code :

  ```
  foreach (var item in Data)
  {
  var element = GetUIElement(item);

  //...
  }

  public FrameworkElement GetUIElement()
  {
      CustomUserControl control = new CustomUserControl();
      control.StartButton.Style = Application.Current.Resources["StandardButton"] as Style;
      return control;
  }
  ```

Comment: show your code......

Comment: Define too much memory?

Comment: @Blam, by too much memory I mean that when the application start, it consumes for example 50 MB, and for each itaration of the loop the amount of memory increases (I can see that with TaskManager for example).

Comment: Yes, memory will increase.  What does the memory get up to?  What do you call too much memory?

Comment: I have 4 GB of RAM, in the TaskManager my application consumes 1.5 GB, I dont think that it's a normal behavior, when I run my application I cant use anything else

Answer (score 1):

from what you've shown there is nothing wrong here, GC doesn't kick in automatically just because an object is de-referenced.  If there is a problem, the code you are showing isn't part of it.

If you have a real leak it would *possibly due* to that created control being stored/ref'd someplace else.

Comment: you can create a simple WPF application, in the main window add a button, in the click event of the button put a for loop in which you instantiate a usercontrol, run the application and watch the memory increasing ( it depends of the size of your usercontrol)

Comment: yes, memory will accumulate but that is not abnormal, the question is does it ever get GC, i am willing to bet it does.

Comment: yes, usercontrols are destroyed after the loop, the problem is when the loop is iterating the memory increases significantly, I wonder if there is something to do to destroy the usercontrol in the loop

Comment: so you're not **ADDING** these created controls anywhere?  I'd like to see more of the code, if you're not adding the control to any Controls list then what is the point of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You can call the garbage:

```
System.GC.Collect();
```

But, I just want to say that your code seem to be strange if you really need it...
Do you know that you can create a ListBox with a custom item template ?

Comment: I tried GC.Collect() and it does not work, and I'm not putting my controls in a ListBox, I just create usercontrols in a loop to export them as a .jpg file

Comment: When did you used it ? GC.Collect will request the garbage collector to try to destroy all objects who are unused.
If you have to store all your UserControl in a List, and after the List will be convert to jpg. You can't destroy yours UserControl before the jpg is created. And the GarbageCollector will destroy them only after the end of your creation.

Can you create multiple images than one ? After the creation of your "splitted image" you could destroy the UseControls which are used.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you contend your application consumes too much memory?

The GC will collect memory when it needs to.

If GC is waiting until the end of the loop to collect that is because the GC has determined it did not need memory while in the loop.

If the memory comes back down at the end of the loop then there is not a memory leak.

How much memory does Task Manager report?

So your app consumes 1.5 GB of memory.
GC is probably still doing its job.
It is collecting memory then it needs to.

Your app is is consuming so many resources that you cannot run other applications.
That does not mean the GC is not doing its job.

What is the purpose of 1000 user controls that you discard?

You could do this but it is not going to fix your program

```
foreach (var item in Data)
{
   using (var element = GetUIElement(item))
   {
       //...
   }
   System.GC.Collect();
}
```

Comment: when I run the application, the total memory is 3.8 GB, I'm on windows 7, my application consumes 1.5 GB